# Vi and Vim for Android Studio

Tags: ide, ideavim

I used to use the Eclipse IDE for Android development under which I used to use a paid software called viPlugin from the web which allowed me to use vim in that IDE.

However, Android developers have now switched to an Android Studio based on the IntelliJ platform, and, as a result, I doubt I can still install and use my plugin in such IDE.

Can someone please point to me to what I would use to use vi or vim under the Android Studio platform based on IntelliJ?

The tags seem to suggest IdeaVim might be what I'm looking for (from IntelliJ IDEA). What is the best way to install it and use it in Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdeaVim is not vi or vim, it is a plugin that emulates some of vim things in intellij products: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim

As for installation, it should be available from within Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't IdeaVim emulate all of vim functionality? I need to use Android Studio but I also need to use vim functionality.

Comment: Can you open a file in an external vim editor from within Android Studio, in some manner (for instance by right clicking or setting a global configuration parametr in the options)?